# Access subform does not show data from linked table correctly

Tags: ms-access

I have a linked table `"SELECTSYSTEM2"` on MS SQL Server that is created with autoincrement ID as primary key and 4 more columns `[SYS, MANDT, SYS_TYPE, LIC_SYS]`. 
Then I run this procedure to link the table and it works perfectly, as the table shows in the linked table list and it is editable.

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
ODBCTableName = "dbo.SELECTSYSTEM"
AccessTableName = "SELECTSYSTEM"
db.TableDefs.Refresh
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If tdf.Name = AccessTableName Then
        db.TableDefs.Delete tdf.Name
        Exit For
    End If
Next tdf
Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(AccessTableName)

tdf.SourceTableName = ODBCTableName
tdf.Connect = strConn
db.TableDefs.Append tdf
```

The problem is when I try to link it directly to the subform `"selectsyssub"` in the form `"CheckLicence"` as in the snippet below.

```
Forms!CheckLicence!selectsyssub.SourceObject = "Table.SELECTSYSTEM2"
```

The other tables that are not assigned primary key (I know, bad practice) and the tables that are assigned primary key from unique string values (no row-numbering or auto-incrementing) are all showing correctly in subforms.

I tried to change the `LinkMasterFields` and `LinkChildFields`, as on the snippet below, but it gives me `Run-time error 2335: You must specify the same number of fields when you set the LinkChildFields and LinkMasterFields properties.`

```
Forms!CheckLicence!selectsyssub.LinkMasterFields = "ID, SYS, MANDT, SYS_TYPE, SEL_SYS"
Forms!CheckLicence!selectsyssub.LinkChildFields = "ID, SYS, MANDT, SYS_TYPE, SEL_SYS"
```

Any ideas how to show correctly the properly linked table from MS SQL server directly into the subform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything got resolved when I renamed the `ID` field to `SYSID`.